# Python: collecting the links from the site

Tags: python, url, hyperlink, urllib

**My aim:** I want to get all links that are present on the given site.

**My problem:** In case when the site opens and no additional content shows up after some time the method below works fine.

```
import lxml.html, urllib
connection = urllib.urlopen('http://www.youtube-mp3.org/?c#v=l8F4vdF-bJc')
dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
   print(link)
```

Unfortunately, the code above is not able to get the links from the content of the site that shows up after some period of time. ( for example this site: http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE  provides the link to the file after the conversion is finished and the above method is unable to catch this link)

**My question:** How can I get links with Python that show up on the site after some periond of the time?

Comment: You'd have to crawl it again. It sounds like you want a program that predicts the future state of the page.

Comment: I want a program that opens a site and waits untill additional content shows up :) However, I can not do that by refreshing the site because this additional content shows up about 10 seconds after refreshing.

Comment: maybe it is added by javascript?

Comment: I dont know... You can open the link that I provided and check what is the problem.

Comment: Yes it appears to be added with javascripttr.

Comment: If it's added by javascript, you won't be able to get it using lxml, you need something that is able to interpret javascript (i.e. a browser engine, like webkit). There are some Python libraries for this (one of them is `webscraping`), but if you're not bound to using Python, I'd suggest you use `casperjs`.

Comment: I would recommend using Selenium. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/